# How can I use latest accessToken in Hilt with SocketIO?

Tags: android, kotlin, sockets, socket.io, dagger-hilt

I am using Hilt and implementing socket.

Here's the repository Module for creating repos.

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object RepositoryModule {
    @Provides
    fun provideSocketRepository(socket: Socket): SocketRepository {
        return SocketRepository(socket)
    }
}
```

And here's ServiceModule to inject Socket to SocketRepository.

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object ServiceModule {
    @Provides
    fun provideSocket(): Socket {
        logd("socket: accessToken: ${Common.accessToken}")
        val options = IO.Options().apply {
            timeout = 30000
            reconnection = true
            reconnectionDelay = 1000
            reconnectionAttempts = 300
            transports = arrayOf(WebSocket.NAME)
            extraHeaders = mapOf(
                "Authorization" to listOf("Bearer ${Common.accessToken}"),
                "Content-Type" to listOf("application/json"),
                "identity" to listOf("app")
            )
        }
        return IO.socket(UrlType.BACK_OFFICE_SERVER.getUrl(), options)
    }
}
```

The problem is

1. `Common.accessToken` is global variable which needs refactoring and also it's updated after sign in. However, Socket is needed globally for entire app process. So, the timing is after injection. How can it get the latest accessToken using hilt?
2. I should connect & disconnect Socket programmatically at some points. If I use hilt it will keep injecting to the repo class. Is it Okay the instance to be alive when I try to disconnect it? for example, `socket.disconnect` without `socket = null` and then `socket.connect` to reconnect socket when it needs to be connected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, `Socket` shouldn't be injected, instead it is wrapped in a Manager class which will handle the logic and being injected into Repositories.

You can have an singleton `AuthManager` class which controls the login and token flow (you can define the module yourself):

```
class AuthManager @Inject constructor() {
    val token = MutableStateFlow<String?>(null)

    suspend fun signIn() {
        // Do sign in stuff, then update your token
        token.emit(newToken)
    }
}
```

Then your `SocketManager` class has `AuthManager` as dependencies:

```
class SocketManager @Inject constructor(authManager: AuthManager) {
    val socket = MutableStateFlow<Socket?>(null)

    init {
        authManager.token.collect {
            // Token updated, recreated your socket here and emit new socket to collector
            socket.emit or socket.trySend
        }
    }
}
```

`SocketManager` is Singleton too (you can define the Module yourself)

Lastly, anywhere you want to use the socket, like in `Activity`, inject `SocketManager` and collect the socket as needed:

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MyActivity: AppCompatActivity {
    @Inject
    lateinit var socketManager: SocketManager

    fun onCreate() {
        lifecycleScope.launch {
            repeatOnLifecycle(Lifecycle.State.STARTED) {
                socketManager.socket.collect {
                    // Use your socket here, socket will be changed after token changed and this code block is called
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not? That's the end-point.

Comment: You mean Why not make `Socket` injectable? Because Socket is mutable and can be recreated by outside scope. And when Socket is changed, it has to notify everything that is currently using it, and it's not the case that Dependency injection can handle directly. It needs a wrapper class (which is injectable) and use `Flow` to notify event

Comment: No, SocketRepository. So, I guess, `socketManager.socket.collect` should be in the Repository.

Comment: Yes you can use a proper MVVM structure here, I usually do it like this: Activity/Fragment - ViewModel - Repository - Service/Manager (injected into repository and usually singleton)